# MySQL - multiple GROUP_CONCAT on multiple TABLES (Server Error)

Tags: mysql

I have table and query like this:
[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aeb75f/21)

```
SELECT P.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `trait_name` ORDER BY `trait_id` SEPARATOR ', ') AS traits,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `filter_name` ORDER BY `filter_id` SEPARATOR ', ') AS filters
FROM `products` P 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `personality_traits` 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `product_to_traits` 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `filters` 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `product_to_filters` 
GROUP BY P.`product_name`
```

I want to select all products and display all traits and filters to which a given product belongs (traits and filters are in separate tables).

This solution works perfectly fine on my localhost, but unfortunately not on the target server.

How else could I write this query?

**edit:**
when I remove one of the GROUP_CONCAT's (and and the corresponding NATURAL JOIN's) my server can handle this. When added second GROUP_CONCAT, server is loading my query for some time and finale throws "500 The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." . I have basic (personal) hosting plan on OVH

When trying to run query directly in phpmyadmin I receive:
[image: error in phpmyadmin]
thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try it on the target server?

Comment: when I remove one of the GROUP_CONCAT's (and and the corresponding NATURAL JOIN's) my server can handle this. When added second GROUP_CONCAT, server is loading my query for some time and finale throws "500 The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." . I have basic (personal) hosting plan on OVH

Comment: If you get a 500 error you need to check the server log to see the actual error message.

Comment: Add alias and then try, may be it will work.

Comment: logs are not really helpful
[error]  AH10141: FastCGI: comm with server "/www/config/admin.php" aborted: idle timeout (160 sec)
[error]  AH10149: FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably fails because it is not a valid aggregation query: the `select` clause must be consistent with the `group by` clause.

Make `product_id` the primary key of table `products`. Then, just change the `GROUP BY` clause to:

```
GROUP BY p.`product_id`
```

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: @Elijah: what happens when you follow the steps suggested in my answer?

Comment: thank you for your help. After making changes you suggested still same error (500 - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.)

Comment: @Elijah: you need to check the server logs and bring the actual error message from the database.

Comment: on logs there is only:  [error] AH10141: FastCGI: comm with server "/www/config/admin.php" aborted: idle timeout (160 sec) [error] AH10149: FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server